# How do I get the value from radiobuttons?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm trying to make a program in python tkinter that creates 3 radiobuttons for different difficulties for the user to choose. I created a variable diffLevel = IntVar() and I'm trying to change it using those radiobuttons. Then, when the user has chosen the difficulty, he presses a button that activates a command that tries to read the value of diffLevel and does different commands depending on its value. But, for some reason, it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
win = Tk()
win.geometry('250x250+650+250')
diffLevel = IntVar()
diffChoiceE = Radiobutton(win, text="Easy", variable=diffLevel, value=0)
diffChoiceE.place(x=10, y=10)
diffChoiceM = Radiobutton(win, text="Medium", variable=diffLevel, value=1)
diffChoiceM.place(x=10, y=35)
diffChoiceH = Radiobutton(win, text="Hard", variable=diffLevel, value=2)
diffChoiceH.place(x=10, y=60)
def diffSet():
    a = diffLevel.get()
    if a == 0:
        setSpades()
    elif a == 1:
        setSpades()
        setHearts()
    elif a == 2:
        setSpades()
        setHearts()
        setClubs()
        setDiamonds()
    win.destroy()
ch = Button(win, text="Choose", width=7, height=1, command=diffSet)
ch.place(x=100, y=80)
win.mainloop()
```

I tried printing 'a', but for some reason, it says '0', even though I selected the radiobutton that makes diffLevel equal 1 or 2. I tried using the ttk module, but then the radiobuttons don't work and all act as if they were pressed. So how can I get the correct value from diffLevel?

Comment: Likely causes for a Var to not work: calling `Tk()` more than once, creating a widget prior to calling `Tk()`, referring to the Var only with a local variable so that it gets garbage-collected before it's actually used.  I don't see any of these problems in your code, but it's obviously an excerpt from a larger program, so I have no idea what you've done elsewhere.  We need a [mcve] - something that actually runs, that actually exhibits the problem.

Comment: @jasonharper oh, I realised I created a different window before this using Tk(), I wanted to make a window that asks the difficulty level, and then another window that actually runs the game. I'll tr to do it differently, thank you for your help.

Comment: The proper way to create additional windows is `Toplevel()`.  Each instance of `Tk()` has its own independent set of Vars; trying to use one with a widget that belongs to a different instance will silently fail.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code a little bit to run on my computer but it seems that the code is working appropriately for me.

```
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry('250x250+650+250')
    diffLevel = IntVar()
    diffChoiceE = Radiobutton(win, text="Easy", variable=diffLevel, value=0)
    diffChoiceE.place(x=10, y=10)
    diffChoiceM = Radiobutton(win, text="Medium", variable=diffLevel, value=1)
    diffChoiceM.place(x=10, y=35)
    diffChoiceH = Radiobutton(win, text="Hard", variable=diffLevel, value=2)
    diffChoiceH.place(x=10, y=60)
    def diffSet():
        a = diffLevel.get()
        print('Values of a: ',a)
        if a == 0:
            print('Spades')
        elif a == 1:
            print('Spades&Hearts')
        elif a == 2:
            print('Spades&Hearts&Clubs&Diamonds')
        #win.destroy()
    ch = Button(win, text="Choose", width=7, height=1, command=diffSet)
    ch.place(x=100, y=80)
    win.mainloop()
```

I have selected each radio button and they are all working currently printing:

```
    Values of a:  0
    Spades
    Values of a:  1
    Spades&Hearts
    Values of a:  2
    Spades&Hearts&Clubs&Diamonds
```

I am using python 3.7 and TkVersion 8.6. Which version are you using ?

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I have understood the problem. There were two windows in the program, both of which used Tk(), and that is why it didn't work. Still, thank you for your help.